# spacy - token is not OOV but does not have a vector

Tags: spacy, word-embedding

I am using English-medium for spacy, and I encountered a situation that tests my understanding of the output.

In short, I have a word that is not OOV (`token.is_oov == False`) but does not have a vector (`token.has_vector == False`).

More than likely, there is an obvious thing that I am overlooking, but intuitively I understand the `OOV` to lack a vector, and in this case, a 300 length vector of 0s.

Simply, how is it possible for a vector to be missing for a token that is in-vocabulary?

Answer (score 1):

For my future self:  I wasn't thinking about the language model.

Per the [docs](https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_md), 685K tokens of which 20k have vectors.  Top-N for vectors makes sense.